# Events seems to vanish upon projection linking

Tags: events, projection, event-driven, eventstoredb

I am using the EventStore solution for the event-driven approach in my new project. I've noticed an issue where emitting an event and linking to a stream seems to make previous events disappear from the stream.

For instance, I have an event stream named `Quest-3` that initially contains three events: quest-created and two occurrences of quest_started. However, when I emit a new event and link it to the stream using a projection, some of the previous events seem to vanish.

IE:
event stream `Quest-3`:
[image]
reading the stream now returns the 3 events, quest-created and 2x of quest_started.

but whenever I emit something that links to the stream it seemingly vanishes:

example of emit:
[image]

`projection` that picks it up:

```
 fromCategory('user')
    .when({
        $init: function () {
            return {
            };
        },
        quest_started: function (state, event) {
          linkTo("quest-" + event.data.questId, event);
        },
    });
```

Result on `quest-3` stream:
[image]

I do notice that event # is different, and by checking previous one, example `event#0` (earlier attempts) I see that it does exist:
[image]

But the `event#5`  used in first image, does not exist anymore.
Upon reading the stream, I only see the three quest_started events and not the ones that were present a few moments ago.

I'm trying to understand what might be causing this issue and why it appears to remove the previous events, or the reason behind why I cant read the `quest_created` events anymore.

EDIT:

The quest-created was created by:

```
  static async appendEvent(streamName, event) {
        try {
          await EventHandler.client.appendToStream(streamName, event);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error appending event:', error.message);
        }
      }
```

IE for creating quest:

```
async create(ignoreExist = false) {
    try {
        let Quest_exist = await this.exist_quest(this.questId);
        let additional = {eventType:QUEST_CREATED};
        
        if (Quest_exist && !ignoreExist) {
            throw Error('Quest with id ' + this.questId + ' already exists');
        }
             EventHandler.sendEvent('quest-' + this.questId,QUEST_CREATED,{...additional, ...this.questData});
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("error occured creating Quest",error.message);
    }
    
}
```

called with:

```
   let QuestData = {
        questId : 3,
        title : 'Quest 1',
        description : 'Do 10 thefts',
        startingRequirements : {rank: 1},
        endingRequirements :{action: 'theft', type: 'success', amount: 10},
        steps : [
            {
                stepId: 1,
                description: "do 10 failed thefts",
                requirements: {rank: 1},
                rewards: {experience: 50},
                dependencies: [{
                    channel: "weather",
                    condition: "Sunny",
                }]
            }
        ],
        rewards : {experience: 100},
        dependencies : [{
                    channel: "weather",
                    condition: "cloudy",
                }]
    };


let xx = new Quest(QuestData);
xx.create();
```

Edit2:
full projection:

```
fromCategory('user')
.when({
    $init: function () {
        return {
            totalHealths: {}
        };
    },

    quest_started: function (state, event) {
       linkTo("quest-" + event.data.questId, event, { expectedVersion: event.eventNumber });
// Link to the "queststream" with the original event
    },
});
```

Comment: - was `quest-3` containing events prior you created the projection ?
( i.e did you append to `quest-3` yourself ?)  


- did you delete the projection & recreated it?
 ( you could have deleted the emitted stream doing that )

Comment: @ylorph quest-3 was containing events prior to projection creation. And I didn't delete and recreate the projection. I did append yo quest-3 myself.

Comment: I see from [this discussion](https://discuss.eventstore.com/t/projections-and-linkto/27/3) that events linked with `linkTo` are not visible unless the projection is running in persistent mode. Is your projection set to persistent mode?

Comment: @VonC yes its set to presistent mode

Comment: OK. Make sure the stream names are consistent in all operations, including reading and writing events. And double-check the projection script for any conditions that might inadvertently exclude certain events from being linked. Also, make sure that there are no ACLs that could be preventing the events from being read or written correctly.

Comment: yeah projection script are listed here, and so are the rest of events.

Comment: Is the projection filtering out the `quest-created` event? The provided projection code only links `quest_started` events. Check the `appendEvent` method to confirm that it is not inadvertently affecting the visibility of events.

Comment: no, my projection is not filtering it out. sec, updating with full projection

Comment: @maria: the projection engine should refuse to write to a stream that was already appended to by other means than the projection that tries to append to it.
( effectively , the projection owns the stream it's appending to using linkto() or emit() )
I've tried the step you described: existing quest-3 stream,  creating the projection, appending event to a user-1 sttream. the projection faulted because of the reason I stated.
Could you describe precisely the step you took ?
I suspect you resseted the streams appended to when creating / updating your projecction

Comment: @ylorph I'm not currently available to check the code.  What I did was: add the create event to the quest-3, 2: made my projection , 3: emitted the topic to tigger projection and then quest-3 only have the linked projection and not my created quest event.